# sqlconnection is not defined

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to update some code. I have a vb file that begins with this...

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Configuration

<script runat="server">
```

...and it is failing here...

```
Using oConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("tps_write").ConnectionString())
```

The error it returns is...

> "Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined."

Am I missing some system class?

EDIT: I updated the code to this...

```
Using oConn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("tps_write").ConnectionString())
```

...and it accepts it. Why do I need to explicitly write out System.Data.SqlClient every time I use an object from that class???

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Data.dll ?

Comment: See comment on Jeff's answer. Also, I tried to simply type in "Imports System.Data.dll" and it says it does not recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out this line was the issue...

```
Using oConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("tps_write").ConnectionString())
```

...instead of using "tps_write," I changed the permission to "tpsWrite." Apparently the tps_write is an outdated permission no longer used here at work. I wish the error messages were more clear.  ;)

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 2):

I came across this thread when searching for help with a similar issue of not being able to create an SQL connection in a **vb.net .NET5** Windows Desktop Application. I was also getting the error of "sqlconnection is not defined".

My solution was to add a NuGet package called "**System.Data.SqlClient**" by Microsoft. You can open the NuGet Package manager by going to **Tools** > **NuGet Package Manager...** > **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**

Hopefully, this will help you or others looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: I updated the code to this...
>
> Using oConn As
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection =
>   New
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("tps_write").ConnectionString())
>
> ...and it accepts it. Why do I need to
>   explicitly write out
>   System.Data.SqlClient every time I use
>   an object from that class???

My best guess is that there's another class out there called `SqlConnection` and .NET doesn't know which type to use until you specify the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` one explicitly.

Comment: @Ant, I edited my answer after reading your edit. Any other classes or anything in your app named `SqlConnection`?

Comment: Good call out. I think that might be the issue. I will have to investigate further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a web application, you might be missing a reference to System.Data. Right click the project in Solution Explorer, and go to Add References. On the .NET tab, select System.Data.dll and click OK.

Comment: Try it without the ".dll". Was System.Data in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified your connection string in the web.config. You should see a tag in there like this

```
<connectionStrings>
<--! Below is your connection string>
<add name="ConnName" connectionString="Data Source=PROGRAMMER2\SQLServer;Initial Catalog=PPSSecurity;Integrated Security=true;" />
</connectionStrings>
```